# numpy.ravel_multi_index error - trying to obtain indices

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am using `numpy.ravel_multi_index` in order to convert a set of nd-indices to a list of linear/ flat indices.

After providing my nd tuple of arrays which looks like this (x, y, z):

```
([13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], 
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], 
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26])
```

And the dimensions of the original matrix which the "flat indices" should be cast:

```
(42, 36, 50)
```

This is throwing an error saying:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (14,) (22,) (6,)
```

However I'm not sure why this is? These indices came from the matrix with dim (42, 36, 50), so why is this a problem?

Comment: I see the problem, arrays must the same length!